# DataGridViewButtonColumn icon

Tags: vb.net

i am using vb.net 2.0 and i would like to set an icon or image in a DataGridViewButtonColumn. I know the class has no member for it. Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best answer is from http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/b0dfb55c-8bad-4c2d-aa72-36d8c138484e/

But as usual, you Google vb.Net and get answers in C#. I use C# to vb.net tool on the developerfusionwebsite to help me convert to vb.net but usually end up changing a fair amount.

Once you have a pointer this one is quite easy really.

In the `dataGridView_CellPainting` event add something like this

```
Private Sub InvoiceLinesDataGridView_CellPainting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs) Handles InvoiceLinesDataGridView.CellPainting

    If e.ColumnIndex = 3 AndAlso e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
        e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All)

        Dim bmpFind As Bitmap = My.Resources.binoc16_h1
        Dim ico As Icon = Icon.FromHandle(bmpFind.GetHicon)
        e.Graphics.DrawIcon(ico, e.CellBounds.Left + 3, e.CellBounds.Top + 3)
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Just to explain this a little, I wanted to use a resource which is a bitmap so I am converting that to an icon also. This works really well for me and I get a proper button column with an image. The column index is a bit rough as that could change so I was looking to refer using the column name - shouldn't be too hard but you get the idea. SO much easier than the other options I have see around that get you making an extended custom column type.

This really should have just been part of the original control and I cannot fathom why MS crippled the grid so much. I have been trying to use third party controls like Telerik but the originals always seem to be more stable so am now seeing if I can stick with vanilla controls and adding my on extensions where required.

Answer (score 2):

I created a method that can be called in the CellPainting datagridview event.

```
  Public Shared Sub SetImageToDataGridViewButtonColumn_CallInCellPaintingEvent(ByRef img As Bitmap, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs)
        e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All & (DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentBackground) & (DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground))
        Dim destRect As Rectangle = New Rectangle(e.CellBounds.X + (e.CellBounds.Width - img.Width) / 2, e.CellBounds.Y + (e.CellBounds.Height - img.Height) / 2, img.Width, img.Height)
        Dim srcRect As Rectangle = New Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height)
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, destRect, srcRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
        e.Handled = True
  End Sub
```

In the CellPainting event, call this method passing the image you want on the button and e.  Ensure you use some sort of condition to set on the column you need, this example the If specifies column 0.  Also notice I have my image in My.Resources:

```
Private Sub dgv_CellPainting(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs) Handles dgv.CellPainting
    If (e.ColumnIndex = 0 And e.RowIndex >= 0) Then
        SetImageToDataGridViewButtonColumn_CallInCellPaintingEvent(My.Resources.myImg, e)
    End If
End Sub
```

Tips:  I found 16x16 png were perfect for my use.  You can resize using http://images.my-addr.com/resize_png_online_tool-free_png_resizer_for_web.php

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a DataGridViewImageColumn add attach an event to the grid's CellContentClick event (in the event process only the events comming from the column/columns that is/are images)